# What is the Canon LP-E6NH operating temperature range?

Tags: canon, battery

I recently bought a 3rd party (DSTE) replacement battery for my Canon 5d MkIII (https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B092QNQF63?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details) and was alarmed to read in the info leaflet:

> .. if exposed to extreme cold (10°C/50°F), the efffective operational time decreases significantly. Exposure to temperatures below 0°/32°F will render the battery inoperative

I expect to be able to use my camera below freezing. Reading about people's experiences with the Canon original (LP-E6NH) I found that people used this in temperatures much lower than freezing without any issues, but I have been unable to find official figures from Canon.

Can anyone point me to anywhere I might find this info? Or can anyone tell me, more generally, whether this is an unusually high temperature limit?

Comment: [This](https://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/8/0300007348/06/eos5d-mk3-im8-en.pdf) manual says that the working temperature is 0°C to 40°C.  It also suggests that at 0°C you can take 850 shots.  But as you mention, there are many reports online about using you camera in sub-zero temps such as [this](https://www.alaskaphotographics.com/blog/2012/12/17/canon-5d-mark-iii-lp-e6-battery-test-in-31-degree-temperatures/) .

Comment: But my experience with an Asako action cam in sub freezing is that the battery chemistry simply freezes up almost instantly, and when restored to above freezing temps it comes back to life. But my iPhone always seemed to work! GoPro have a sub-zero rated battery for their cameras, so your experience is going to depend on the manufacturing of battery and the quality of it.  But the take away seems to be to have multiple batteries kept warm and ready to go, or even use a battery eliminator and have the real battery against your body.

Comment: Sounds like there's plenty of info the comments for an answer, y'all.

Comment: since when is 10°C/50°F "extreme cold"?

Comment: If you have a live preview feature, counter-intuitively in the cold, that extra current draw will keep the battery and internals warmer longer, resulting in more shots until frozen-dead than with the optical viewfinder.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [documentation](https://www.canon-europe.com/cameras/eos-5d-mark-iv/specifications/) and personal experience:

Canon cameras have operational temperature interval between 0 and 40 degree C. And because these cameras use LP-E6 serie of batteries I understand this is accepted temperature for batteries too. I am not aware of any **official** documentation for operations outside this interval.

My personal experience with temperatures around 0 show batteries show low charge in short time. But you can replace with other battery. And rotate them for some time. The general advice is to keep batteries close to your body. The heat of your body will mitigate the effect of loose charge too fast in low temperatures. Some internal pocket can do the work.

Answer (score 0):

I can only tell, what I know.
I own both, original Canon LP-E6NH and Smallrig [thrid-pary](https://www.smallrig.com.de/SmallRig-LP-E6NH-USB-C-Rechargeable-Camera-Battery-4264.html) batterys.

- The temperature rating for the smallrig batterys is 0℃ ~ 45℃
- For the original canon batterys, I can't find any official information, but the Canon R5 *(using this type of battery)* is rated from 1°C ~ 40°C

Of course, the manufacturers only tell you operating temperatures where they can guarantee, that their product operates as advertised, so that you can't come to them after shooting one day below 0°C and try to refund your products because the batterys didn't last as long.
Anyway, this does not mean, that it's impossible to use the batterys outside of that temperature range.

So far for the official informationn now about real-world usage:.
I have used my Canon R5 with original and thrid-party batterys for over three years in both, extremely hot and cold, envronments *(I'd say something from -15°C to ~ 45°C <-- Temperature of the camera body, not the air)*

The only time, my camera did something weird, was on a triathlon in blazing sun, constantly shooting with high framerate, when suddenly the autofocus stopped working until I restarted the camera (I can't tell if it was the lens or the camera)

As winter isn't getting verry cold in Germany, the lowes temperature I was shooting at, was about -15°C for about 5h.
At such "low" temperatures, batteries tend not to last as long. One trick would be to store the baterys inside your jacket or otherwise near your body to keep them warm.
In addition, batteries should [never be charged below](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acsenergylett.9b00663) ~10°C. (most chargers do not verify this).

I do not know that brand, you wanted to buy the batterys from, but 16£ (~19€) for two batterys seem extremely low for me. Please don't expect them to operate nearly as good as the original ones.
Sure, the originals are waay to expensive, but I'd say, 32£ (38€) for one battery are a fair price. I'd also recommend [this product](https://www.smallrig.com.de/smallrig-lp-e6nh-camera-battery-and-charger-kit-3821.html).

I hope, that I could help you.